# Why won't getelementbyid display twice on page?

Tags: javascript

This simple javascript countdown won't display twice on my page. I understand with getElementbyId requires that only one ID be associated with it, but changing to getElementbyClassName and making the adjustments accordingly, also doesn't work.

[Codepen here.](https://codepen.io/newnam/pen/aXqNqW)

Please assist

```js
 //JS Countdown
 var countDownDate = new Date("Feb 13, 2019 23:59:00");
 initializeClock('cd-clock', countDownDate);

 function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
   var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
   var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
   var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
   var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
   var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
   return {
  'total': t,
  'days': days,
  'hours': hours,
  'minutes': minutes,
  'seconds': seconds
   };
 }

 function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
   var clock = document.getElementById(id);
   var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
   var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
   var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
   var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

   function updateClock() {
  var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

  daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
  hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
  minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
  secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

  if (t.total <= 0) {
    clearInterval(timeinterval);
  }
   }

   updateClock();
   var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
 }
```

```css
#cd-clock {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5em;
}

.card.countdown {
    z-index: 100;
}

    #cd-clock > div {
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #cd-clock div > span {
        padding: 2px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        display: inline-block;
    }

.tiny-text {
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="container text-center mb-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="card countdown">
        <h3 class="card-header">Timer #1</h3>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div id="cd-clock">
            <div>
              <span class="days"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">DAYS</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span class="hours"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">HOURS</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span class="minutes"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">MINUTES</div>
            </div>  
            <div>
              <span class="seconds"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">SECONDS</div>
            </div>  
          </div>                        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="card countdown">
        <h3 class="card-header">Timer #2</h3>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div id="cd-clock">
            <div>
              <span class="days"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">DAYS</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span class="hours"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">HOURS</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span class="minutes"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">MINUTES</div>
            </div>  
            <div>
              <span class="seconds"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">SECONDS</div>
            </div>  
          </div>                        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because you're repeating `id="cd-clock"`. Ids need to be unique to the page. Change the logic to use classes instead. You stated that you attempted to do that but the question shows no evidence of this which we can help you to debug

Comment: And it's `getElementsByClassName()`, "elements" plural

Comment: Thanks. Instead of ClassName, I was using class. I see my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
//JS Countdown
 var countDownDate = new Date("Feb 13, 2019 23:59:00");
 initializeClock('cd-clock', countDownDate);

 function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
   var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
   var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
   var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
   var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
   var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
   return {
  'total': t,
  'days': days,
  'hours': hours,
  'minutes': minutes,
  'seconds': seconds
   };
 }

 function initializeClock(className, endtime) {
   var clock = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    Array.from(clock).forEach(clock => {
    var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
   var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
   var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
   var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');
    setInterval(() => updateClock(daysSpan, hoursSpan, minutesSpan, secondsSpan), 1000);
    updateClock(daysSpan, hoursSpan, minutesSpan, secondsSpan);
   
    })
   
   function updateClock(dSpan, hSpan, mSpan, sSpan)     {
  var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

  dSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
  hSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
  mSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
  sSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

  if (t.total <= 0) {
    return;
   }
   }
 }
```

```css
#cd-clock {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5em;
}

.card.countdown {
    z-index: 100;
}

    .cd-clock > div {
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .cd-clock div > span {
        padding: 2px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        display: inline-block;
    }

.tiny-text {
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="container text-center mb-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="card countdown">
        <h3 class="card-header">Timer #1</h3>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="cd-clock">
            <div>
              <span class="days"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">DAYS</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span class="hours"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">HOURS</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span class="minutes"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">MINUTES</div>
            </div>  
            <div>
              <span class="seconds"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">SECONDS</div>
            </div>  
          </div>                        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="card countdown">
        <h3 class="card-header">Timer #2</h3>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="cd-clock">
            <div>
              <span class="days"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">DAYS</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span class="hours"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">HOURS</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span class="minutes"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">MINUTES</div>
            </div>  
            <div>
              <span class="seconds"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">SECONDS</div>
            </div>  
          </div>                        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Instead of ClassName, I was using class. I see my mistake.Thanks for the assist.

Comment: Happy to help @webfrogs. Feel free to upvote if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You were correct about the id part. IDs are supposed to be *unique* in, like, any thing programming-related, so `getElementById` will only return the first element that match given id.

`getElementsByClassName` (note the s: Element**s**) will return a nodelist (similar to array) of all elements that match that class name. Afterward you will need to loop through each of those element to work on them:

```js
//JS Countdown
var countDownDate = new Date("Feb 13, 2019 23:59:00");
initializeClock('cd-clock', countDownDate);

function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(className, endtime) {
  var clocks = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

  for (let clock of clocks) {
    updateClock(clock, endtime);
    var timeinterval = setInterval(() => updateClock(clock, endtime), 1000);
  }
}

function updateClock(clock, endtime) {
  var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
  hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
  minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
  secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

  if (t.total <= 0) {
    clearInterval(timeinterval);
  }
}
```

```css
#cd-clock {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5em;
}

.card.countdown {
  z-index: 100;
}

#cd-clock>div {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#cd-clock div>span {
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tiny-text {
  padding-top: 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="container text-center mb-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="card countdown">
        <h3 class="card-header">Timer #1</h3>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="cd-clock">
            <div>
              <span class="days"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">DAYS</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span class="hours"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">HOURS</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span class="minutes"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">MINUTES</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span class="seconds"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">SECONDS</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="card countdown">
        <h3 class="card-header">Timer #2</h3>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="cd-clock">
            <div>
              <span class="days"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">DAYS</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span class="hours"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">HOURS</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span class="minutes"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">MINUTES</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span class="seconds"></span>
              <div class="tiny-text">SECONDS</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```